# Changing syntax of WMTS Source to XYZ Layer

Tags: leaflet, gis, qgis

I am looking to add a WMTS source in my Leaflet application.
To do this, I pull up the XML file of WMTS source and extract the variables I need to create the syntax for XYZ Layer URL.
The XYZ Layer can then be loaded into Leaflet &/or QGIS.

Example (WORKING):
https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/NkcnS0qk4w2wasOJ/arcgis/rest/services/OrthoImagery2019/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml?cacheKey=886383ae702b176e

Would change to (WORKING):
[https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/NkcnS0qk4w2wasOJ/arcgis/rest/services/OrthoImagery2019/MapServer/WMTS/tile/1.0.0/OrthoImagery2019/default/default028mm/{z}/{y}/{x}.png](https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/NkcnS0qk4w2wasOJ/arcgis/rest/services/OrthoImagery2019/MapServer/WMTS/tile/1.0.0/OrthoImagery2019/default/default028mm/%7Bz%7D/%7By%7D/%7Bx%7D.png)

Example (NOT WORKING):
https://web2.co.ottertail.mn.us/arcgis/rest/services/Photography/2021_Photo/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml

Would change to (NOT WORKING):
[https://web2.co.ottertail.mn.us/arcgis/rest/services/Photography/2021_Photo/MapServer/WMTS/tile/1.0.0/Photography_2021_Photo/default/default028mm/{z}/{y}/{x}.png](https://web2.co.ottertail.mn.us/arcgis/rest/services/Photography/2021_Photo/MapServer/WMTS/tile/1.0.0/Photography_2021_Photo/default/default028mm/%7Bz%7D/%7By%7D/%7Bx%7D.png)

CRS of source is EPSG: 3857 so I do not believe this to be the issue.

Can someone assist? Thank you!

Comment: See the list of Leaflet plugins, search for "WMTS".

Comment: @IvanSanchez thank you - I dont believe I need a plugin to use WMTS source though? Here is an example below of how I integrate the source into Leaflet (I use the XML file to locate variables and then create XYZ Tile Layer source)

var santaclaracaImagery = L.tileLayer('https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/NkcnS0qk4w2wasOJ/arcgis/rest/services/OrthoImagery2019/MapServer/WMTS/tile/1.0.0/OrthoImagery2019/default/default028mm/{z}/{y}/{x}.png', {
    minZoom: 1,
    maxZoom: 28,
    attribution: ""
});

Comment: IIRC one of those can parse the `getCapabilities` XML document so you don't have to worry about tile template URLs.

Comment: I believe this is the plugin you are referring to: https://github.com/alcalin/L.TileLayer.WMTS

I took the example file and replaced the WMTS url and layer name with:

let url = 'https://web2.co.ottertail.mn.us/arcgis/rest/services/Photography/2021_Photo/MapServer/WMTS';
                
let options = {
                    tileMatrixSet:'g',
                    layer:'Photography_2021_Photo'

I am having trouble determining what to use for 'let url ='. The current url I have is not loading.

Comment: @IvanSanchez any way you could test out that URL with the WMTS plugin you are referring to? I am starting to think it is a problem with the WMTS server..